jakarta @Nonnull annotation not working in intellij
below code should throw an exception

import jakarta.annotation.Nonnull;

public class test89 {
    public String processString(@Nonnull String input) {
        // Your method logic here
        return "Processed: " + input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test89 exampleService = new test89();
        String result = exampleService.processString(null);
        System.out.println(result);

        
    }
}

but giving output as
`
Processed: null

Process finished with exit code 0`

it should throw Exception

Where in the specification or Javadoc did you see a promise of an exception being thrown?

Where should the annotation processing happen in your small code example?
You don't use dependency injection or call any validation, so your code works as I would expect it.
The annotation doesn't do anything by itself, it is just a marker for other code to process.
See the Jakarta Annotations specification and Javadoc.
